# Flutter slider disable Min or Max

Tags: flutter

According to flutter document https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html

> The slider will be disabled if onChanged is null or if the range given by min..max is empty (i.e. if min is equal to max).

I have a use case that want to disable min or max slider not whole slider , I want to have a check box **without max value** and only disable max slider not min

How can I do that?

Comment: What you want to is not quite clear. Can you explain it further?

Comment: a slider without min or max is pointless - how can you imagine selecting a value form 0 to ∞ (infinity)?

Comment: No @pskink, he doesn't want to remove max slider, he just wants to disable it, and make the min only active. He is finding the way for that. I hope that clears your doubt. It is clearly not about **0 to ∞**

Comment: @Alok yes exactly , I am not taking about infinity, We have two interactive "thumb" , one for max and one for min , I want to disable max thumb in some conditions